# How Do I Pass An Initial Values to Custom Form Using Django-Userena

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have been searching the web, (and StackOverflow), for an answer to what appears to be a REALLY simple problem. I am using django-userena with a custom form.

Inside my form.py is:

```
class RegistrationForm(SignupFormOnlyEmail):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=30, required=True, error_messages={'required':'Please Provide Your First Name'})
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=30, required=True)
    email2 = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=75)), label=_("Retype Email"), required=True)
    parent_type = forms.ChoiceField(label="I am a", choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    child_count = forms.ChoiceField(label="My Kids", choices=KID_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select)
    grade = forms.ChoiceField(label="My Classroom", choices=GRADE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select)
    tos = forms.BooleanField(label="I accept the Terms of Use.", required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.initial = kwargs.pop('initial', None)
        kidCount = self.initial['child_count']
        account_type = self.initial['parent_type']

        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Inside of my urls.py I put:

```
url(r'^membership/signup/$', signup_view, name='userena_signup'),
```

My custom view looks like this:

```
def signup_view(request):

    form = RegistrationForm(initial={'parent_type':request.session['parent_type'],'child_count':request.session['child_count']})
    response = userena_views.signup(request,  signup_form=form, extra_context={'section':'Membership','pagetitle':'Sign Up'})
    return response
```

When I post the form and go to the /membership/signup/, I get a "TypeError" of

> 'RegistrationForm' object is not callable

Here is a dump of the stack trace:

> Traceback:
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/Users/lawrenceleach/Dropbox/Sites/django/wonderville/membership/views.py" in signup_view
>     42.     response = userena_views.signup(request,  signup_form=form, extra_context={'section':'Membership','pagetitle':'Sign Up'})
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/userena/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     28.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/userena/views.py" in signup
>     115.     form = signup_form()
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /membership/signup/
>   Exception Value: 'RegistrationForm' object is not callable

Like I said, I'm sure the answer is staring me right in the face and I just can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to pass the initial form values as a dictionary object to the "extra_context" variable of the form call in the view. If had been using Django's built-in form tool then what I originally had done above would have worked. I posted the issue to the Userena folks. It appears to be a bug within their system.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass form class to `signup` function insted of object. Look to the [code](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py#L76) for more information.

Insted of:

```
form = RegistrationForm(initial={'parent_type':request.session['parent_type'],'child_count':request.session['child_count']})
response = userena_views.signup(request,  signup_form=form, extra_context={'section':'Membership','pagetitle':'Sign Up'})
```

It should be:

```
response = userena_views.signup(request,  signup_form=RegistrationForm, extra_context={'section':'Membership','pagetitle':'Sign Up'})
```

Because inside `userena_views.signup` there is `form = signup_form()`. Ofcourse now you lose your form initial values.

Comment: I'm doing that in my custom view. I've looked at the userena code already. I must not be understanding what you are saying. Could you elaborate a little on what you see wrong with my code?

Comment: I did this initially. However I NEED those initial values to be passed to the form.

Comment: I know, but this is a problem with `userena` - there is no option to pass additional form parameters (e.g. `initial`). You can try wrap form creation inside function and pass it as `signup_form` argument. It should work, but this is ugly hack.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I think I will try passing values to the template, (via extra_content) and set my initial values that way.